# Build a model with cross-validation on entire dataset to learn insights?

Tags: python, regression, xgboost, cross-validation, hyperparameter-tuning

Goal : Use XGBoost regression to learn insights from data. Prediction or forecasting not needed.

Hypothesis : If the model fits the entire dataset well, it can maybe capture its "physics" in the system.

Technique:

1. Define hyperparameter space.
2. Use entire dataset (no training and testing split)
3. Initialize model with hyper-parameters.
4. Split the entire dataset to maybe 10 folds.
5. Rather than just finding cross-val scores on each fold, I build the model using each fold. So I start a loop of 10 folds, and build the initialized model for each fold. Thus the final model will be built/trained on all the ten folds. I am also storing the RMSE of each fold.
6. I use this fitted model to predict my entire dataset. Then I use RMSE of this prediction in the hyperparameter algorithm for it to be minimized. I can also add the variance of the RMSES in the folds to the algorithm as an uncertainity.
7. Best parameters chosen based on the RMSE in step 5 (entire dataset).

I know CV is not for building, but since my goal is not prediction, my goal is that the model fits the entire dataset well enough to understand its "physics".

Is this a valid approach?

I am using hyperopt for hyper-parameter tuning.

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand step 5 and - in parts - step 6 correctly, but it sounds to me that you plan to do CV, just not with the CV methods from sklearn. And maybe with some variation in the details.

Comment: Just to be sure: (1) to build a model for each fold means you use exactly the data from that fold as training data? (2) on which data do you evaluate the model that was trained for one fold? (3) the final model is trained all the data and evaluated on each fold individually?

Comment: Yes so for Fold 1, I fit the model on train part of Fold1. Then in Fold 2, I fit the previously fitted model on train part of Fold 2.